# How to keep track of editing in any of the controls from a group of controls

Tags: c#, user-controls, event-handling

My program is designed to change and save user settings. The program consists of many usercontrols. I need to show message to the user to save the settings before closing the application when it was produced at least one unsaved changing.
There are too many controls and it will be inefficiently to define an event for each control.I don't sure that it is only one way to solve my problem. Any advice please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't really any options that can do what you are asking.  If your controls are bound to an object, you can use the object to see if it has any changes, assuming the object implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Another method would be be programatically add a handler (for the "changing" event such as `TextChanged` for a TextBox)  to each control that maps to a single sub that sets a flag.

Comment: Yes, I just figured out it. I will use the second method.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

May be this will be usefull for someone:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public bool EditedFlag=false;

    private void Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EditedFlag=true;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
        {
            ControlEvents(ctrl);
        }
    }

    public void ControlEvents<T>(T sender)
    {            
        if (sender is TextBox) 
        {
            var obj = sender as TextBox;
            obj.TextChanged+= new EventHandler(Changed);
        }
        if (sender is CheckBox)
        {
            var obj = sender as CheckBox;
            obj.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(Changed);
        }
        if (sender is ComboBox)
        {
            var obj = sender as ComboBox;
            obj.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(Changed);
        }

    }
}
```